# How to get/retain the ORIGINAL session in a Java web application after getting the control back from a PAYMENT GATEWAY site?

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, payment-gateway

I am trying to integrate a payment gateway with a Java web application deployed on Tomcat 7.0. The problem I am facing right now is that I am not able to access the ORIGINAL session that was there (i.e., the one before the control is forwarded from the Java web application to the payment gateway site) after the control is returned back from the payment gateway (after successful/unsuccessful payment). I need that session (i.e., the one that existed before going to the payment gateway site) to save the results of the payment with the other user & cart details.

Is it generally taken care by the Payment Gateway API or should it be explicitly handled by us in our Java web application? If the later is true, any help on how to retain the session would be of great help.

Regards,
Shiva